# How to execute try-catch included in one tab after a button of another tab is clicked-Blackberry

Tags: java, database, sqlite, blackberry, user-interface

I am working on the below code where i have created 3 tabs in pane manager of Blackberry.The first tab allows the user to select a date range against a customer name and fetch results of that customer to be displayed in the 3rd tab in a grid format.

1. So the first tab has 2 date fields and a customer text field.Along with a search button.
2. On click of the search button it selects the records of the search and jumps to the third tab for displaying in grid format.
3. The third tab has try catch statements for inserting the table record elements string by string onto the grid.

The problem now is as soon i open my application, and click on the third tab, it shows me the grid filled with junk values.It does not wait for the search button of first tab to be clicked and then showing the result.If i happen to close the application and reopen it, I find the 3 rd tab showing the result of my previous search.

Here is the code:

```
   // setup the tab model with 3 tabs
  final PaneManagerModel model = new PaneManagerModel();
  model.enableLooping( true );

  // setup the first tab   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager( 
      Field.USE_ALL_HEIGHT | Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH |
      Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL | Manager.NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL );
  LabelField lbl = new LabelField( "Content for tab 1", Field.FOCUSABLE );
  vfm.add( lbl );

  TextField1 = new TextField(" Name:            ",null)
     {
            protected boolean keyChar(char ch, int status, int time) 
            {
            if (CharacterUtilities.isLetter(ch) || (ch == Characters.BACKSPACE || (ch == Characters.SPACE))) 
            {
            return super.keyChar(ch, status, time);
            }
           return true;
            }
        };
     vfm.add(TextField1);

    SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");//dd/MM/yyyy
     Date now = new Date();
     String strDate = sdfDate.format(now);

     TextField2 = new TextField("\n From:             ",strDate);
     vfm.add(TextField2);

    // TextField3 = new TextField("TO: ",null);
     //vfm.add(TextField3); 

     SimpleDateFormat sdfDate1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");//dd/MM/yyyy
     Date later = new Date();
     String strDate1 = sdfDate1.format(later);

     TextField3 = new TextField("\n To:                 ",strDate1);
     vfm.add(TextField3);

     ButtonField showInputButton = new ButtonField("  Search  ",ButtonField.FIELD_HCENTER | ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);
      showInputButton.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() 
      {
            public void fieldChanged(Field field,int context) 
            {
                    Dialog.alert(TextField1.getText());
                    try
                  {    
                    //Open or create the database
                    Database db = DatabaseFactory.openOrCreate("database1.db");
                    //Insert onto table
                    Statement statement13 = db.createStatement("INSERT into 
                    Temp4(date,bill,narration) VALUES (('"+TextField3.getText()+"'),(SELECT balance FROM Temp3),('Opening Balance'))");
                    statement13.prepare();
                    statement13.execute(); 

                    Statement statement131 = db.createStatement("INSERT INTO Temp4(date,bill,narration,id) select date,amount,narration,id from Bills where name=\'"+TextField1.getText()+"\' AND substr(date,7)||substr(date,4,2)||substr(date,1,2) < substr (\'"+TextField3.getText()+"\',7)||substr (\'"+TextField3.getText()+"\',4,2)||substr (\'"+TextField3.getText()+"\',1,2) ");
                    statement131.prepare();
                    statement131.execute();      // date INTEGER,bill INTEGER,rec INTEGER,narration TEXT,id INTEGER
                    statement131.close(); 

                    Statement statement132 = db.createStatement("INSERT INTO  Temp4(date,rec,narration,id) select date,amount,narration,id from Receipts where name=\'"+TextField1.getText()+"\' AND substr(date,7)||substr(date,4,2)||substr(date,1,2) < substr (\'"+TextField3.getText()+"\',7)||substr (\'"+TextField3.getText()+"\',4,2)||substr (\'"+TextField3.getText()+"\',1,2) ");
                    statement132.prepare();
                    statement132.execute();       
                    statement132.close(); 

                     db.close();
                    }
                    catch( Exception e ) 
                    {         
                        System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    model.getView().jumpTo(2,PaneManagerView.DIRECTION_NONE);
                  }
        }

                    );

      vfm.add(showInputButton);
      LabelField myLbl = new MyLabelField( "Ledger" );
 NullField nullFld = new NullField( Field.FOCUSABLE );
  HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager();
  hfm.add( nullFld );
  hfm.add( myLbl );

  Pane pane = new Pane( hfm, vfm );
  model.addPane( pane );

   //Here ends tab 1 code
```

//Setup the third tab- XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
      vfm = new VerticalFieldManager( 
      Field.USE_ALL_HEIGHT | Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH |
      Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL | Manager.NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL );

      myLbl = new MyLabelField( "Daily Report" );

      //Adding grid format for fetching from temp4 table----------------


 final GridFieldManager grid = new GridFieldManager(10,5,0); 

    grid.add(new LabelField("Date")
    {
       public void paint(Graphics graphics)
       {
         graphics.setColor(Color.CYAN);
         super.paint(graphics);
       }
     });
    grid.add(new LabelField("Bill")
    {
       public void paint(Graphics graphics)
       {
         graphics.setColor(Color.CYAN);
         super.paint(graphics);
       }
     });
    grid.add(new LabelField("Receipt")
    {
       public void paint(Graphics graphics)
       {
         graphics.setColor(Color.CYAN);
         super.paint(graphics);
       }
     });
    grid.add(new LabelField("Narration")
    {
       public void paint(Graphics graphics)
       {
         graphics.setColor(Color.CYAN);
         super.paint(graphics);
       }
     });
    grid.add(new LabelField("ID")
    {
       public void paint(Graphics graphics)
       {
         graphics.setColor(Color.CYAN);
         super.paint(graphics);
       }
     });

    grid.setColumnPadding(20);
    grid.setRowPadding(20);
//try catch was here


       try
               {

                  //Open or create the database
                    Database db = DatabaseFactory.openOrCreate("database1.db"); 

                    Statement statement55 = db.createStatement("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Temp4(date INTEGER,bill INTEGER,rec INTEGER,narration TEXT,id INTEGER)");
                    statement55.prepare();
                    statement55.execute();       
                    statement55.close();

                    Statement statement56 = db.createStatement("SELECT date,bill,rec,narration,id FROM Temp4 ORDER BY ROWID DESC");
                    statement56.prepare();
                    statement56.execute();

                            Cursor c = statement56.getCursor();

                            //Get to the row of grid
                             for (int i = 1; i < grid.getRowCount(); i++)
                             {
                                    System.out.println("Inside for first loops");
                                    //Get to the column of grid
                                for (int j = 0; j < grid.getColumnCount() ; j++)
                                {
                                   System.out.println("Inside for second loops");
                                   //Get to the row of temp4 table
                                   while(c.next()) 
                                   {

                                      System.out.println("Inside while"); 
                                        Row r;
                                        r = c.getRow();
                                        //Get to the column of temp4 table

                                        for (int k = 4; k >=0; k--)
                                        {

                                            System.out.println("Inside for loops");
                                            //Check for whether column retrieved is date or naraation
                                            if(k==0 || k==3)
                                            {
                                                System.out.println("Retrieving date or narration");
                                                grid.insert(new LabelField(r.getString(k))
                                                {
                                                    public void paint(Graphics graphics)
                                                    {
                                                    graphics.setColor(Color.GOLD);
                                                    super.paint(graphics);
                                                    }
                                                 },i,j);


                                            }  
                                            else
                                            {   
                                                //Check for whether column retrieved is bills,rec or id
                                                System.out.println("Retrieving other values"); 
                                                String p = "" + r.getObject(k);

                                                //if(r.getString(k) != null)
                                                //{ 
                                                grid.insert(new LabelField(p)
                                                {
                                                    public void paint(Graphics graphics)
                                                    {
                                                    graphics.setColor(Color.GOLD);
                                                    super.paint(graphics);
                                                    }
                                                 },i,j); 
                                               //  } 


                                            }   
                                           grid.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createLinearGradientBackground(Color.MIDNIGHTBLUE,Color.STEELBLUE,Color.MIDNIGHTBLUE,Color.STEELBLUE));
                                           //grid.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createLinearGradientBackground(Color.GOLD,Color.CHOCOLATE,Color.GOLDENROD,Color.CORAL));

                                        } 
                                         System.out.println("Exiting while");                        
                                      }

                                      System.out.println("Exiting sec for");
                                      break;
                                  }
                                System.out.println("Exiting first for");
                                break;
                               } 
                               statement56.close(); 
                               db.close();
                  }

                  catch( Exception e ) 
                  {         
                        System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
                        e.printStackTrace();
                  }  





    vfm.add(grid);

   //----------------grid ends---------------------------------------- 

  nullFld = new NullField( Field.FOCUSABLE );
  hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager();
  hfm.add( nullFld );
  hfm.add( myLbl );

   pane = new Pane( hfm, vfm );
   model.addPane( pane );
```

And now the rest of the set up

```
      // select the tab to be displayed
  model.setCurrentlySelectedIndex( 0 );    

  // setup the rest of the components
  HorizontalTabTitleView titleView = new HorizontalTabTitleView( Field.FOCUSABLE );
  titleView.setNumberOfDisplayedTabs( 3 );
  titleView.setModel( model );

  PaneView paneView = new PaneView( Field.FOCUSABLE );
  paneView.setModel( model );

  PaneManagerView view = new PaneManagerView( 
          Field.FOCUSABLE  | Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL | 
          Manager.NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL | Manager.USE_ALL_HEIGHT | 
          Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH, 
          titleView, paneView );
  view.setModel( model );
  model.setView( view );

  // configure the Controller
  HorizontalTabController controller = new HorizontalTabController();
  controller.setModel( model );
  controller.setView( view );
  model.setController( controller );
  view.setController( controller );


  // add the tab manager to the MainScreen
  this.add( view );

 }
```

I have also tried disabling the third pane and adding it inside the first tab search implementation but gives an error as the third tab is defined after first.
Also i have tried including the try catch of third tab in a function so that it can be invoked on button click of fist tab.But that gives an error too of "Illegal start of expression"

PLease suggest a solution.Anyone who can spare a thought to this code and aid a solution will be highly appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at the BlackBerry **MainScreen** methods for `onExposed` and `onObscured`?

> **protected void onExposed()**
>
> Invoked when this screen is revealed by a screen getting popped off
>   the display stack. Subclasses of screen should override this method
>   for special handling.
>
> The complimenting callback is **onObscured()**.

---

> **protected void onObscured()**
>
> Invoked when this screen is obscured by a new screen pushed on the
>   display stack. Subclasses of screen should override this method for
>   special handling.
>
> The complimenting callback is **onExposed()**.